# How to Write a Data Trigger to open Popup by Clicking dynamic Button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, popup, datatrigger

I'm having a dynamic Button in my WPF application, while clicking any one of the button the popup should open and the corresponding Button should turn the Background Color to Orange and rest of the Button should be in default Backgroud Color using DataTrigger and one more condition, at the time of Popup close, the corresponding Button Background Color should turn to the Default Color.

> Note: I Can't able to give Name for the Buttons because of Dynamic
>   Creation. Here I placed 5 Buttons without Name Property, Consider the
>   Button as Dynamic Creation

My XAML Source Code is

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Height="30px" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="One" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Two" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Three" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Four" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Five" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Popup Name="sPop" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to Popup Screen"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: 1) You should use `ToggelButton` instead of `Button` so that you can maintain the checked state. 2) Give a name to Popup if it's not dynamic. 3) Write a style (apply to all ToggleButton) which set the IsOpen to True.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. I Can't able to replace the Button, its my requirement. Can you please post your answer, It really helpful for me. The Popup is not Dynamic, so we can give the Name.

Comment: If you don't want to change to ToggleButton then you have to maintain the state of checked/clicked property of button so that appropriate background color can be applied.

Comment: You can use the Tag Property to maintain the State of the Button.

Comment: Can you give name for popup?

Comment: you can give the Name for the Popup as "sPop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it using DataTriggers. DataTriggers are for Data-Based scenarios, so if you are using DataBinding, then use them.

Recommended approach :

Assign a name to your Popup. And use Behaviors.

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" RightOperand="True"/>
                    </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                </ei:ConditionBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup1}" PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

To use Blend assemblies :

Add reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and following namespaces :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

To revert back old Background of the source Button :

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" RightOperand="True"/>
                    </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                </ei:ConditionBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <!-- Store Button's old Background -->
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup1}" PropertyName="Tag" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"/>

            <!-- Change Button's Background -->
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Purple"/>

            <!-- Open Popup -->
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup1}" PropertyName="IsOpen" Value="True"/>

            <!-- Save this Button, Popup will use it to revert back its old Background -->
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Popup1}" PropertyName="PlacementTarget" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"/>

        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<Popup x:Name="Popup1" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction 
                        TargetObject="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Popup}}" 
                        PropertyName="Background" 
                        Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Popup}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to Popup Screen"/>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Kind reply. I works fine. one more condition, at the time of Popup close, the corresponding Button Background Color should turn to the Default Color.

Comment: Thanks alot... its working fine as per my requirement.

Comment: I implemented this code in my Main Project, I got an error at the time of button click "Cannot find a Property named "IsOpen" on type "Button" - it throws from <!-- Open Popup -->. Kindly give your solution pls.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Earlier u said, its working fine, now u said its not working.

Comment: In my Sample Project its working fine. My Popup is placed in the Parent View and the Button is in app.xaml, these two was called in one child View.

Comment: In my Sample Project its working fine. My Popup is placed in the Parent View and the Button is in app.xaml, these two was called in one child View.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Thats a separate question, plz ask it separately.

Comment: I posted the Querry in the following URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327280/how-to-write-datatrigger-to-visible-the-filter-icon-in-the-datagrid-while-on-mou

It contains a DataGrid with Filter Icon Button Filter Icon Should be visible only on mouse hover to the corresponding column or Popup IsOpen otherwise it should be in collapsed state.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve what you asking for without using `DataTrigger`.
This is simple style trigger for changing background:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Each your button can handle `Click` event:

```
<Button Content="One" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" />
...
```

And we need to take your `Popup` somehow. I just named it:

```
<Popup Name="popup" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
...
```

Click event is simple:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (popup.IsOpen) { popup.IsOpen = false; }
    popup.PlacementTarget = button;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

So it works like you want.